# React Navigation + React Native Vision Camera: keep camera visible through navigation animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-vision-camera

I'm developing an App using React Navigation to navigate through stack screens. One of these screens contains the Camera component from RN Vision Camera (https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera). I navigate to that screen using a custom animation that slides from the left side.

The "issue" is that when I navigate to that screen the Camera container remains black (null) until the focus (entrance) animation **ends**. In addition, the Camera container also turns black (null) when the blur (leaving) animation **begins**.

I'd like to get a similiar behaviour as the one I get using the Expo-Camera. That is: seing the Camera preview in the container as soon as the Camera preview is available when the focus animation **begins**, but most importantly, keep the Camera visible until the blur animation **ends**. I would emphasize that this is the default behaviour for Expo-Camera, I don't have to code anything extra to achieve this.

I'm using the front Camera in both cases.

I've already tried to set the Camera prop isActive={true} at all time.

Thanks in advance!